# WebSphere MQ: Disable logging

Tags: ibm-mq

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc%2Ffa12570_.htm talks about log configuration, but does not say if logging can be disabled altogether. Is this possible?

Comment: This is used by the product to implement many of its features like persistence, message delivery and assurance etc. Why would you want that disabled? If you are having problems with linear logging you can use circular logging instead.  The answer is No.

Comment: Ok thank you. We were trying to measure the performance impact of logging.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance impact MQ uses log files. These are not log files in the generic sense they instead keep a record of the in-flight transactions.